# How to use AppCompatActivity with Fabric to get Timeline?

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, appcompatactivity

I am following [fabric's documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html) to get a timeline. It works fine if I use ListActivity according to their instruction. But I want to add my own toolbar so I used AppCompatActivity instead. Here is part of my java file:

```
public class TimelineActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

public static final String QUERY = "QUERY";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder()
            .query(getIntent().getStringExtra(QUERY))
            .build();
    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
            .setTimeline(searchTimeline)
            .build();
    ListView tweetList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tweet_list);
    tweetList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

And here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TimeLineActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Please wait . . ."/>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/tweet_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#e1e8ed"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem is, it doesn't show any result. I am stuck with the "Please wait . . ." TextView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered it myself, since I didn't extend ListActivity, I need to add the TextView with Id = empty, manually using setEmptyView().

```
    TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    ListView tweetList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tweet_list);

    tweetList.setEmptyView(emptyText);
    tweetList.setAdapter(adapter);
```